# CVE-2017-7529 - Exploit details?

Tags: exploit, server, source-code, cve, nginx

https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-7529

Where can I find the exploit details for this CVE? Usually sites like exploit-db.com include the PoC exploit for a given vuln but I can't find it for this nginx CVE.

Comment: A CVE assignments doesn't necessarily mean there is a PoC.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here:

https://github.com/nixawk/labs/issues/15

Most CVE proof of concept (PoCs) can be found on [exploit-db](https://www.exploit-db.com/), [Github](https://github.com) or [Security Focu](http://www.securityfocus.com/)s.